# Mismatch in maximum ram supported by OEM(16GB) and dmidecode output(32GB). Which is right?

Tags: upgrade, laptop, hardware, ram, dmidecode

I want to upgrade my laptop ram to 32GB but manufacture manual says only 16GB is supported.
Laptop: HP 15-ay503tx
Motherboard: HP 81EC (Version: 61.30)
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-6200U (2.3 GHz, up to 2.8 GHz, 3 MB cache, 2 cores)

```
dmidecode output:
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0028
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-slot 1(top)
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 0000
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number:                     
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0028
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom-slot 2(under)
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Micron
    Serial Number: 
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: 8ATF1G64HZ-2G3B1    
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

lshw output:

```
*-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 28
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns) [empty]
          vendor: 0000
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: Bottom-slot 1(top)
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: 8ATF1G64HZ-2G3B1
          vendor: Micron
          physical id: 1
          serial: 
          slot: Bottom-slot 2(under)
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
```

[HP Manuals](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-15-ay500-notebook-pc-series/12229013/model/13673661/manuals)

[HP Maintenance And Service Manual Page 14](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05087748.pdf)

[Crucial Motherboard Compatibility](https://www.crucial.in/compatible-upgrade-for/hp---compaq/hp-81ec-motherboard)

[HP Forum Similar Query](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/15-ay503tx-RAM-upgradable-upto-32gb/td-p/5935853)

Can I upgrade ram to 32GB(2x16GB)?

Comment: Intel says 32 Gb - see https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88193/intel-core-i56200u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-2-80-ghz.html .

Comment: Yes, but upon searching I understood that amount of RAM is also dependent motherboard.

Comment: I think the output of the command `sudo lshw -class memory` will be much clear. Please add the output of this command to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It means the firmware supports it but the manufacturer didn't test it, so you get no guarantees.

You could try it and it will likely work, but you may be unlucky and  hit some piece of HW being unable to function correctly, or you hit something unexpected like the Motherboard not delivering enough power to the RAM modules

It sounds suspicious Min & Max Voltage are 1.5 V yet the Configured Voltage is 1.2 V (1.2v is the reference, 1.5 is actually dangerous).

It also depends on whether the RAM sicks are low or high density (the number of "chips" in it is usually how you notice)

If you find someone else with the same HW who already tried, you'd get the definitive answer

#### Disclaimer

There is a very low chance, but non-zero, that trying these 16GB modules into your MB could damage the motherboard. It's a very low chance, but you need to weight whether you:

- Are able to afford wasting money on 2x16GB modules (if it doesn't work)
- Are able to afford losing the laptop entirely (if it fries your motherboard)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Intel CPU on your laptop supports up to 32GB RAM, but that is only half of the story. If the motherboard doesn't have sufficient bus capacity to support 32GB RAM, then RAM over 16GB might not work properly. I would go with the manufacturer's manual and not try to install more than 16GB RAM on your laptop.